# Elements displaying in UI Auotmation, but not MSAA

Tags: ui-automation, screen-readers, microsoft-accessibility

Forgive me as I'm not an expert in this matter...

We use MSAA and a venodors app to capture user's visited webpages. I have some machines that do not capture the visited web pages. The pages are captured through MSAA (Im using MS's inspect utility to view UI Automation and MSAA).

For the problematic machines, the elements expand/ display under  UI automation, but not under the MSAA view. To be short with this, anyone have any idea why MSAA would appear to be 'disabled' on these machines??

Appreciate any help in this.

Comment: Which browser do you use?